Do League of Legends analytics sites provide any meta-game/tactical advantages?
I recently started with League and have a hard time winning. People told me to use analytics sites like op.gg, u.gg or sagemode.gg, but I am not sure if they are really worth it.
I also considered paying for a coach or skill capped. Has anyone experience in how I can rank-up effectively?
